# XCode 4.5.2 - Add Files to Git

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, xcode4.5

I'm a veteran at SVN (on Windows and Linux) but I'm doing a project on XCode and decided to use the built in Git interface. When I commit my changes, it says I've only modified two files (some config files for the project) and not any of my source files. I try to add the files using Source Control -> Add, but the add button is grayed out. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: FYI - In case you didn't notice, Xcode supports `SVN` too. Unless you want to learn `git` it may be easier to stick with `SVN`.

Comment: Well, XCode defaulted to git, so I assumed it would be more suited. IMO it seems to be busted in XCode 4.5.2 (along with a dozen other things). But I'm waiting for someone else to state that.

Comment: I commit my files this way (I think I saw that in a ADC Video): I select all files and ctrl-click it and commit them from the Source Control menu.